# How to use returned result from inner function as a parameter in the outer function?

Tags: python, function, closures

I have a question regarding how to use the returned result from the inner function as a parameter in the outer function.

I tried the following code, but the result was not what I expected:

```
def outer_function(a,b):
    def inner_function(c):
        inner_result = c * 100
        return inner_result 
    return inner_function 
    outer_result = a * b * inner_result 
    return outer_result

some_func = outer_function(10,9)
some_func(9)
```

I expected the result from the `some_func(9)` as `9 * 100 * 10 * 9 = 81000`; instead, the result turned out to be `900`.

I am wondering what I did wrong and how I can use the `inner_result` as a parameter in the `outer_function`?

Comment: Please can you provide some different input data. The fact that you have `9` twice is confusing as to which `9` is presents at which stage of the processing.

Comment: The second `return` is never called. A function can only return once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`outer_function` (like all functions) can only return a single value, yet you're attempting to return both the `inner_function`, and the `outer_result`. The first `return` ends the function, leading to erroneous behavior.

If you don't want to incorporate the `outer_result` calculation into `inner_function` (I'd just do that), you could wrap it in another function that carries out the calculation. That could be done via a `lambda`, or another full `def`:

```
def outer_function(a,b):
    def inner_function(c):
        inner_result = c * 100
        return inner_result
    return lambda c: a * b * inner_function(c)
```

or

```
def outer_function(a,b):
    def inner_function(c):
        inner_result = c * 100
        return inner_result
    def second_inner_function(d):
        return a * b * inner_function(d)
    return second_inner_function
```

Although, again, the `a * b *` calculation should likely just be added into `inner_function` unless for conceptual reasons you really wanted to keep it separate.

Answer (score 1):

When you returned inner_function on line 5. The function ended, so line 6 and 7 didn't get executed.

Answer (score 0):

I got you simple approach for you with some little tweaks in the code:

```
def outer_function(a,b):
    def inner_function(c):
        inner_result = a * b * c * 100
        return inner_result 
    return inner_function 
    

some_func = outer_function(10,9)
print(some_func(9))
```

I hope you can easily understand it now.